# Python simple username/password with dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I am quite new to the Python world and thought it would be great to work through my son's Python book for beginners. I am in the process of combining all the current chapters into creating an interactive 'Choose from list...' in order to familiarise myself with the basics. One of these sections included validating a username/password stored in the code itself, but I thought I would take it a step further and see if I can read from a file.

I have managed to cobble together the following but it will only ever read from the latest line in the password file:

```
with open('password.csv', "r") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    database = [] #creates a list holder for the data
    for row in reader:
        database.append(dict(username=row["username"],
                            password=row["password"]))

authenticated = False
while not authenticated:
        username = input("Enter the username: ")
        password = input("Enter the password: ")
        for row in database:
            userFile = row["username"]
            passwordFile = row["password"]
        if (userFile) == username and (passwordFile) == password:
            authenticated = True
        if authenticated is not True:
            print("Incorrect credentials")
```

Can anybody with a little more experience point me where I have gone wrong? Is this too advanced for my level and should I have done something different?

Comment: What do you mean by "it will only ever read from the latest line in the password file" ? can you show us the content of the file and example input/output from this code?

Comment: What happens when you try to `print(database)` after the `with` indentation?

Comment: The contents of the password.csv are: username,password

Comment: using print(database) does output the entire list (currently two) of usernames and passwords

Comment: @DeepSpace Whenever I add more than one username and password to the password file the previous no longer works i.e. Incorrect credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions but I managed to sort this myself and was simply down to my inexperience in Python. The spacing was incorrect in my code. Simple!